# How do I get the content of an iframe using python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How do I get the content of an iframe using python?
I want to use requests without resorting to selenium, how do I implement this?

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHDuQ.png)

Comment: You can simply use html.parser https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

Comment: the problem is that this approach will not work. Because the content of the iframe is not loaded immediately, but over time

Comment: if the iframe is rendered overtime then you should simulate that iframe using selenium and then use beautifulsoup to get the iframe

Comment: What is the url? @Marko

Comment: @KrkRamaKrishna what if i want the session not to be lost? session in requests will be synchronized with selenium?

Comment: @Karthik Url of what?

Comment: @Karthik  https://m.ok.ru/app/docent

Comment: @Karthik i can give u log and pass if u want

Comment: @Karthik do u have telegram?

Comment: its not personal

Comment: @Karthik u are here?

Comment: i created id..an untranslatable website..i will try

Comment: @Karthik thanku man, i can give u own id

Comment: its ok fine..i will use mines

Comment: In general, I wanted to go to the "docents" application and parse suid there

Comment: To go there you need to go into the games, and select the one you need, and there is a training, you need to go through it so that the game starts @Karthik

Comment: Therefore, I offered my id @Karthik

Comment: Its in russian bro. Unable to read it nor translate it

Comment: its not translatable. u can use my id, you do not need to undergo training in this case(Although it is not difficult) @Karthik